# Dirac delta function and dirac measure

Tags: probability, measure-theory, statistics, dirac-delta

I want to know the relationship between these two things. e.g. What's the results of following integrals? (Let $\mu$ Lebesgue measure, $\nu$ Dirac measure)
$$(1)\int\delta_c(x)\mu(dx)$$
$$(2)\int\delta_c(x)\nu(dx)$$
$$(3)\int f(x)\delta_c(x)\mu(dx)$$
$$(4)\int f(x)\delta_c(x)\nu(dx)$$

Comment: Why do you use the same notation for the Dirac delta distribution $\delta(x)$ defined by $\int_\mathbb{R} \varphi(x) \delta(x)dx = \varphi(0)$ (whenever $\varphi$ is continuous at $0$) and the Dirac measure $\nu((a,b)) = \int_{(a,b)} d\nu(x) =\int_\mathbb{R}1_{x \in (a,b)} d\nu(x)= \int_{(a,b)} \delta(x)dx = 1_{0 \in (a,b)}$ ie. $\int_\mathbb{R} \varphi(x) \delta(x)dx = \int_\mathbb{R} \varphi(x) d\nu(x)=\int_\mathbb{R} \varphi(x) \nu(dx)$ ?

Comment: What does $\delta_c$ mean as a function?

Comment: @reuns, sorry about that but that is what I mean.

Comment: @copper.hat, $\delta_c$ is the dirac delta function. I've corrected the notation in the question.

Comment: @reuns, I've corrected the notation and my question remains the same. What's thes result of these four integrals?

Comment: What did you try given what I wrote ?

Comment: @reuns So is $\int\varphi(x)\delta(x)\nu(dx)$ meaningless or it equals to something?

Comment: What is your guess ?

Comment: @reuns I guess it is meaningless or equals infinity? I'm not sure since I don't know how to use $\delta(x)$ to define a general probability function of a mixed random variable with a measure that is not Lebesgue.

Comment: A useful definition of $\delta(x)$ is $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \varphi(x) \delta(x) dx = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \varphi(x) \frac{1_{|x| < \epsilon}}{2 \epsilon} dx$$ Note you can replace $1_{|x| < \epsilon}$ by $1_{x \in  (\epsilon,3 \epsilon)}$ the result will be the same whenever $\varphi$ is continuous.

Comment: They are not meaningful as functions, but they can be made sense as distributions over $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ via the notion of **convolution**. Indeed, if $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure on $\mathbb{R}$ (which covers OP's all the four cases), then as a distribution, $$ \forall\varphi\in\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}) \ : \quad \int \varphi(c) \int \delta_c(x)\,\mu(\mathrm{d}x) \, \mathrm{d}c = (\delta_0 \star \mu)[\varphi] = \mu[\varphi].$$

Answer (score 2):

So first **the Dirac delta is not and can not be a function** but it is a distribution of order $0$, which can be seen as a measure. This is why it is better to use the notation
$$
\int f(x)\,\delta_c(\mathrm{d}x) = f(c)
$$
or $\langle \delta_c,f\rangle = f(c)$. In particular, there is no general way to multiply two measures.  However, one can multiply a measure by a continuous function. Moreover, one can associate to every measure $\lambda$ that is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure a function $f_\lambda$ and so one can identify these measures with functions by writing $\lambda(\mathrm{d}x) = f_\lambda(x)\,\mu(\mathrm{d}x)$ (and one usually denotes just by $\mathrm{d}x$ the Lebesgue measure so that the associated function is $1$). So one could define the product of $\delta_c$ with $\lambda$ by $(\lambda\delta_c)(\mathrm{d}x) = f_{\lambda}(x)\,\delta_c(\mathrm{d}x)$. In any case, one cannot multiply the Dirac delta with itself.

Knowing all that, lets try to give a meaning to your very formal expressions:
$$\begin{align*}
(1)&& \int 1\, \delta_c(\mathrm{d}x) &= 1
\\
(2)&& \int \delta_c(\mathrm{d}x)^2 &\ \textbf{ has no meaning!} 
\\
(3)&& \int f(x)\,1\, \delta_c(\mathrm{d}x) &= f(c)
\\
(4)&& \int f(x)\,\delta_c(\mathrm{d}x)^2 &\ \textbf{ has no meaning!} 
\end{align*}$$

As usual, this comes from the misconception that $\delta_c$ is a function ...

Edit: I see in the comments you are asking about probability distributions. In general, probability distributions can be measures that are not absolutely with respect to the Lebesgue measure. As an example, $\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}$ is the distribution of the uniform law in $[0,1]$, $\delta_0$ is the distribution of the constant law $\mathbb{P}(X=0)=1$. You can for example then get $f = \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{1}_{[0,1]} + \frac{1}{2} \delta_0$ to get half a chance to get $0$ and half the chance to be in $[0,1]$. But there is no meaning to multiply probability distributions. The product of random variables will imply the convolution product of their probability distributions, and the law of a couple $(X,Y)$ will be the tensor product of their probability distributions (which always make sense for distributions).

Answer (score 1):

In analysis and probability, Dirac's delta $\delta_c$ is commonly seen as **a function defined on a space of functions**. Here are two examples:

- In the **Theory of distribution**s for example $\delta_c$ is defined as  $\delta_c:\mathcal{C}^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^d)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined as $\delta_c\phi = \phi(c)$.  Clearly $\delta_c$ defines a linear function.
- In **measure theory or the thoery of integration**, the $\delta_c$ is defined as a measure on a measurable space $(X,\mathscr{B})$ such that $\delta_c(A)=1$ if $c\in A$, $0$ otherwise. It is easily seen that $\delta_c$ induces a linear function on the space of measurable functions on $(X,\mathscr{B})$ be setting $\delta_cf=f(c)$.

your expressions (1)-(4) are not properly defined unless there is some additional context. For instance, if $\delta_c$ and $\mu$ are measures,  it make sense to talk about the product measure $\delta_c\otimes\mu$:
$$
\int f(x,y)\delta_c(dx)\mu(dy)=\int f(c,y)\mu(dy)$$

If  $\delta_c$ is though of as a  distributions, and may talk about $\delta_c*\phi$, for any $\phi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$

Comment: I would say a functional or a mapping on a space of functions, in order to reserve the word function to functions defined on finite dimensional spaces and avoid the confusions of all these people struggling with the Dirac delta.

Comment: And also write $\delta_c(f)$, $\delta_c[f]$ or $\langle \delta_c, f\rangle$ to emphasise that you are talking about a functional acting on $f$ there, and not a generalisation of the product of functions. The product of the delta with a continuous function is $\delta_c f = f(c)\, \delta_c$